# Maps API for JavaScript - Autocomplete and H.PlacesService

Tags: here-api

I'm writing a web application that should provide an autocomplete component.

So I was thinking to use H.PlacesService to access the low-level Places REST API.

PlacesService.suggest calls the suggest entry point that is deprecated (https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/topics_api/resource-suggest.html)

- why?
- what should I use? the autosuggest entry point?

Anyway, the autosuggest entry point (I guess should replace the suggest entry point) is not implemented by the placesServices.

So at the end

- Is using PlacesService wrapper a good approach?

Answer (score 0):

Go for HERE REST API.
See two examples, using [typescript](https://developer.here.com/blog/suggesting-places-with-jquery-geolocation-and-the-here-places-api) or [jquery-ui](https://developer.here.com/blog/suggesting-places-with-jquery-geolocation-and-here-maps-part-2)

Answer (score 0):

There is also a Geocoder Autocomplete API which could be a possibility:

https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder-autocomplete/topics/key-concepts.html

Here you can find some example with the JS API:

https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3/geocoder_autocomplete